# swf adaptative resolution, change depending user's monitor

Tags: html, flash

Is it posible to make a flash site, which will change the size when the vistors resolution is diferent? Practicly, every visitor will see the same size of the site, even if he has 800x600 or 1280x1024??

Maybe making html go fullscreen but make the swf occupy only 80% of the screen, so it always have the same proportion to the users monitors.

Do you have any example?

```
<center>
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>
<embed src="left.swf" quality="high" scale="exactfit" bgcolor="#000" wmode="transparent" width="150" height="600" />
</td>
<td>
<embed src="MAIN.swf" quality="high"  scale="exactfit" bgcolor="#000" wmode="transparent" width="940" height="600" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</td>
<td>
<embed src="rightr.swf" quality="high" scale="exactfit" bgcolor="#000" wmode="transparent" width="150" height="600" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

Comment: I thought Flash movies always scaled proportionally to the output size *by default*...

Comment: I guess I put too many resolution,so in some computers it seems nice and in others not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your flash to 100% of the HTML page, you can then read the "screen" resolution and even listen for changes (if the window is resized).

```
public function Main():void 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
    stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResized);
    onStageResized()
}

private function onStageResized(e:Event=null):void 
{
    trace(stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight); 
}
```

Comment: how do you embed the flash in your page? swfobject?

Comment: ok, put 100% in width and height and set the following in your css: html, body { height:100%; } body { margin:0; }